# PHP Composer Global Configuration Private Repositories URL List

Tags: php, configuration, composer-php, repository

PHP Composer allows you to define it project's **composer.json** list of urls pointing to private repositories. Example:

```
{
    "require": {
        "vendor/my-private-repo": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:vendor/my-private-repo.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

But whenever I create a new private repo I need to edit all my projects and add that new repo URL to their **composer.json** before I am able to request that new package.

Is there any global composer configuration where I could store URLs to all of my private repos or even better where I can globally set an URL pointing to a resource that will have a list of all my private repos and their URLs up to date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set all repositories in you Composer home directory (find where it is with `composer config --global home`). There is a `config.json` file in which you can add all the global repositories (global on that machine for all your projects).

See the docs on this file: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home-config-json

Unfortunately, you cannot have a central managed way for this out of the box. You could look into [Composer Satis](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md) for this. With Satis you can host a single repository that references where all your packages are located (e.g. Bitbucket, GitHub or otherwise).

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
composer config --global --editor
```

Then next to `config` add `repositories` with yours, e.g.

```
{
  config: {},
  repositories: [
    {
      type: vcs,
      url: git@github.com:vendor/package.git
    }
  ]
}
```