# Is there a way to extract repositories section of composer.json to separate file

Tags: php, composer-php

When working locally on a project I often prefer to add a local directory for developed packages (instead of downloading them from packagist/satis) like this:

```
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../packages/*"
        }
    ],
```

The issue is I do not want to commit that part to the repository.
Is there a way to extract `repositories` section from `composer.json` to a separate (uncommited) file similar to how `auth.json` can be used for credentials?

Answer (score 0):

You can add those repositories to the global config. Commonly that is not within your project tree and therefore you don't commit it.

Global repositories are automatically active in all projects.

For an example, please see this existing answer: [PHP Composer Global Configuration Private Repositories URL List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67982109/367456).

If you want that more project specific, have a different [COMPOSER_HOME parameter](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home) within your development environment, so you can keep the project coniguration more apart from it. You still may want to re-bind the cache to the original one, there are additional parameters you can control that more fine-grained.

Comment: That is nice, but it has 2 drawbacks:
1. If I change COMPOSER_HOME, then my own global config will be ignored, not a big issue but an issue.
2. It requires everyone to remember to put `COMPOSER_HOME=./some/path` to each composer command. That is very error prone. 
So as I understand there is no secondary composer file that I could use?

Comment: @HubertNNN: The COMPOSER_HOME is just a parameter. Keep its default setting then 1.) the global config will not be ignored and 2.) no one needs to remember anything. But in any case, it looks like you could benefit from tooling like a _build tool_ in your [software build](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_build). E.g. a _build manager_ handles all those requirements with ease, it sounds you're still running composer update etc.. Should not be necessary when using version control and especially as you're looking forward to not commit a file - automate your build then.